# Jquery mobile refresh index page on back button

Tags: jquery-mobile, refresh

I have an index page that dynamically loads a json object. if I go to a second page and then I try to go back to the index using back button I'd like to reload index page, so it reloads the json object that could be changed. This is my `index.html` page code:

```html
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Test</title> 
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>      
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page" id="pagina">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="d">
        <h1 style="font-size:14px">test</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" id="content">  
        <ul data-role="listview" id="ul_id" data-theme="b" data-inset="true">
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /content -->
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
    $.getJSON('http://www.test.com/test.php', function(data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    $('#ul_id').append($('<li><a href="' + val +'.cfm" id="'+ val +'"><h3>' + key + '</h3></a></li>'));
    });
    $('#ul_id').listview('refresh');
    });
</script>
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize `pagebeforeshow` or `pageshow` [event](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) like so:

```js
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#pagina", function() {
    //put your code here to manipulate the content
});
```